# How to Use SVN in XP with FTP?

Tags: svn, windows-xp

I am the new to SVN using FTP server. Anyone can give idea for using svn in FTP in Windows XP?

Answer (score 1):

I would check out [Tortoise SVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) if you want a free way to do it with an interface. If you have access to the FTP through a shell you could also use [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) for some awesome command line editing. Whichever one you decide to go with, let me know if you need more help! :D

Answer (score 1):

1. Subversion over FTP isn't supported and doesn't make a lot of sense. Subversion needs some intelligence on the remote server, whether it's `svnserve` or `mod_dav_svn`. Requiring the client to access files on the remote server would be really slow and inefficient (and subversion is already slow enough...)
2. FTP is 1970s technology that really needs to go away ;)